# Leaflet custom icon, react-leaflet, can't build Gatsby project

Tags: leaflet, gatsby, react-leaflet

I've got custom icons working in my Leaflet map just fine when I run `gatsby develop` locally, but when I try to build I get an error related to my custom marker icon:

```
 WebpackError: TypeError: leaflet_src_layer_marker__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Icon is not a constructor
```

Related imports:

```
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, Tooltip, ZoomControl } from 'react-leaflet'
import { Icon } from 'leaflet/src/layer/marker'
```

Create custom icon:

```
// Init custom map icon
  const mapIcon = MapIcon();
  const markerIcon = new Icon({
    iconUrl: mapIcon,
    iconSize: [36, 36],
    iconAnchor: [18, 18],
    shadowSize: [36, 36],
    shadowUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowAnchor: [10, 18],
    popupAnchor: [0, -16],
    tooltipAnchor: [13, -4]
  });
```

JSX:

```
{ markerData.length > 0 ? markerData.map((node, index) => (
            <Marker position={[node.coords.lat, node.coords.lng]} key={`marker-${index}`} icon={markerIcon}>
              <Popup className="leaflet-popup" onOpen={(el) => openPopup(el)}>
                <h5 className="popup-location-title">{node.location_title}</h5>
                <h6 className="popup-address">{node.address}</h6>
                <div className="popup-description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.description }}></div>
                {!!node.embed ?
                  <div className="popup-embed">
                    <Embed url={node.embed} className="popup-media-embed" />
                  </div>
                : null}
              </Popup>
              <Tooltip className="leaflet-tooltip">
                <span className="title">{node.location_title}</span>
                <span className="address">{node.address}</span>
              </Tooltip>
            </Marker>
          )) : null }
```

I've tried all the solutions listed here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/874. I've also looked at several similar questions. Nothing seems to help. For instance, I also tried importing leaflet like so `import * as L from "leaflet"` and like so `import L from "leaflet"`. And then creating the new icon like so  `const markerIcon = L.Icon({`, like so `const markerIcon = L.icon({`, like so `const markerIcon = new L.Icon({`, and like so `const markerIcon = new L.icon({`. I can `console.log(L)`, but none of these works.

I would love some assistance.

Answer (score 8):

Got it to build. I had to wrap the icon construction in a check for the window obj:

```
// Init custom map icon
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const mapIcon = MapIcon();
    markerIcon = new Icon({
      iconUrl: mapIcon,
      iconSize: [36, 36],
      iconAnchor: [18, 18],
      shadowSize: [36, 36],
      shadowUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png',
      shadowAnchor: [10, 18],
      popupAnchor: [0, -16],
      tooltipAnchor: [13, -4]
    });
  }
```

And again when passing the icon to the marker:

```
<Marker position={[node.coords.lat, node.coords.lng]} key={`marker-${index}`} icon={(!!markerIcon) ? markerIcon : null}>
```

Comment: Wasted hours trying to figure out. Never crossed my mind on this one. Thanks for this post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to wrap the icon with this form

```
let icon = ""
if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
icon = Leaflet.icon({
    iconUrl: PointerIcon,
    iconSize: [38, 38],
});
}
```

and add the same validation in the component that is calling it