# React Leaflet works during development, fails on build time, noting to the lack of constructor icon

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, gatsby

I use GatsbyJS, and Leaflet to create a map. The only problem is I want to use multiple icons on the map as a marker icon. Everything works during development, fully functional, but when I try "gatsby build", it fails:

Here is the error

```
                          < Marker
  25 |                       position={[`${genome.coordinate_x}`,`${genome.coordinate_y}`]}
> 26 |                       icon = {new Icon({
     |                               ^
  27 |                         iconUrl: genome.bee_icon.childImageSharp.fluid.src,
  28 |                         iconSize: [60],
  29 |                         iconAnchor: [20, 40]
  WebpackError: TypeError: leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Icon is not a constructor
```

Here is the code of the page

```
import React from "react"
import LayoutNoPadding from "../components/layoutNoPadding"
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, Tooltip } from 'react-leaflet'
import {Icon} from 'leaflet'
import {graphql} from 'gatsby'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import SEO from '../components/SEO'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'


const IndexPage = ({data}) => {
  const {allStrapiGenomes:{nodes:genomes}} = data

  return (
  <LayoutNoPadding>
    <SEO title="WWB" />
        <Map center={[0, 0]} zoom={2} maxZoom={5} minZoom={2} attributionControl={false} >
                <TileLayer
                url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
                 />
                {genomes.map((genome)=> {
                  return (
                    <div className="bee-icons">
                    <Marker
                      position={[`${genome.coordinate_x}`,`${genome.coordinate_y}`]}
                      icon = {new Icon({
                        iconUrl: genome.bee_icon.childImageSharp.fluid.src,
                        iconSize: [60],
                        iconAnchor: [20, 40]
                      })}
                    >
                      <Tooltip>{genome.bee_name}</Tooltip>
                      <Popup>
                        <Img fluid={genome.bee_icon.childImageSharp.fluid} alt={genome.bee_name} />
                        <h1 className="text-xl py-2">{genome.bee_name}</h1>
                        <h1 className="text-lg text-gray-500">{genome.bee_genome}</h1>
                        <p className="text-sm text-gray-700 pb-2">{genome.summary}</p>
                        <Link fade to={`/genomes/${genome.slug}`} className="flex bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4 focus:outline-none text-lg cursor-pointer text-white rounded-full justify-center text-white hover:bg-gray-300 transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out">Read More</Link>
                      </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </div>
                  )
                })}
        </Map>
  </LayoutNoPadding>
  )
}
export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  {
    allStrapiGenomes {
      nodes {
        bee_icon {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
        bee_genome
        coordinate_x
        coordinate_y
        summary
        strapiId
        bee_photo {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
        bee_name
        content
        slug
        }
      }
    }
`
```

I'm sure it has something to do with announcing the Icon constructor inside the marker, is it legit, what is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try calling `Icon()` without the new keyword? https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#icon

Comment: @ksav No, as you can see on the page code, I called the new for making a constructor, somehow it works fine during development [on my computer], but when I hit [gatsby build], it gives me that error:
Thanks again.

Comment: @ksav I just did, and it fails even during development with this code: 
```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
  24 | <Marker
  25 |   position={[`${genome.coordinate_x}`,`${genome.coordinate_y}`]}
> 26 |   icon = { Icon({
  27 |     iconUrl: genome.bee_icon.childImageSharp.fluid.src,
  28 |     iconSize: [60],
  29 |     iconAnchor: [20, 40]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaflet custom icon, react-leaflet, can't build Gatsby project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750863/leaflet-custom-icon-react-leaflet-cant-build-gatsby-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it inside the check `window` condition:

```
    return (
    {typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
      <LayoutNoPadding>
        <SEO title="WWB" />
            <Map center={[0, 0]} zoom={2} maxZoom={5} minZoom={2} attributionControl={false} >
                    <TileLayer
                    url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
                     />
                    {genomes.map((genome)=> {
                      return (
                        <div className="bee-icons">
                        <Marker
                          position={[`${genome.coordinate_x}`,`${genome.coordinate_y}`]}
                          icon = {new Icon({
                            iconUrl: genome.bee_icon.childImageSharp.fluid.src,
                            iconSize: [60],
                            iconAnchor: [20, 40]
                          })}
                        >
                          <Tooltip>{genome.bee_name}</Tooltip>
                          <Popup>
                            <Img fluid={genome.bee_icon.childImageSharp.fluid} alt={genome.bee_name} />
                            <h1 className="text-xl py-2">{genome.bee_name}</h1>
                            <h1 className="text-lg text-gray-500">{genome.bee_genome}</h1>
                            <p className="text-sm text-gray-700 pb-2">{genome.summary}</p>
                            <Link fade to={`/genomes/${genome.slug}`} className="flex bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4 focus:outline-none text-lg cursor-pointer text-white rounded-full justify-center text-white hover:bg-gray-300 transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out">Read More</Link>
                          </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    </div>
                      )
                    })}
            </Map>
      </LayoutNoPadding>
    }      
 )
```

`gatsby develop` occurs in the browser-side, since it creates a socket to refresh and re-hydrate in real-time your components as well as the browser. `gatsby-build` occurs in the server, as you may notice, in the server, there's no window (or any other browser global objects such `document`) so it breaks the code. There are multiple solutions to bypass this issue: from adding a `null` loader to the whole bad dependency from `node_modules` when it's transpiled by webpack to adding a simple condition to check if the `window` it's defined (the solution provided).

You can check for further details in [Debugging HTML builds documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

Comment: This breaks hydration. The output rendered server-side should match the initial render (with the same props) client side in order for reconciliation to work. Instead I recommend using `const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)` so the initial client render matches, then use `useEffect(() => { setReady(true) }, [])` to prompt rendering once the component is “mounted”.

Comment: Many mny thanks @Ferran Buireu, it actually solved my problem.